# rails incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT for umlaut URLs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, character-encoding

In my rails 4 app, I use umlaut URLs like `/geschenk-für-freundin`.
Works fantastically on my development and production (heroku) environment, but every now and then my exception notification gem drops me a mail saying this:

> An ActionView::Template::Error occurred in pages#index:
>
> incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT 
>   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:16:in
>   `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___1108345064192482953_70013471860740'
>
> Request:
>
> - URL        : /geschenke-für-freundin

Visiting the URL and all works fine so I assume this is just an issue for some browsers maybe?
Digging through the exception log, I can see this HTTP_USER_AGENT:

> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like
>   Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36

which looks like an up to date browser kit in my opinion.

I don't know why this is only an issue for some of my visitors but I want to fix it. Any ideas?